# How to setup a CCTextField in Cocos2d v3

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

This is what I got so far:

```
enterName = [CCTextField textFieldWithSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"Tile.png"]];
enterName.fontSize = 16.0f;
enterName.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
enterName.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
enterName.scale = 0.70f;
[self addChild:enterName z:5];
```

Basically, it creates a *microscopic* text field which you can barely click on. The only method that pops up for CCTextField is "textFieldWithSpriteImage."

Bonus help: How to store the string that was typed after enter.
Cheers.

Comment: Try changing contentSize

Comment: Thanks. I removed `enterName.scale = 0.70f;` and added `enterName.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100.0f, 50.0f);` and it is still microscopic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to prevent microscopic CCTextFields in Cocos2d, make sure to set `preferredSize`.

Here is the code which prevents a microscopic textfield:

```
CCSprite *textSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Tile.png"];
enterName = [CCTextField textFieldWithSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"Tile.png"]];
enterName.fontSize = 16.0f;
enterName.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100.0f, 50.0f);
enterName.preferredSize = textSprite.contentSize; // don't forget this !
enterName.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
enterName.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
[self addChild:enterName z:5];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cocos2d there are other ways to incorporate text fields. The most convenient way is Spritebuilder, similar to Storyboard. You can edit the font size, and size of text box without using code. Then you just adjust the Textfield so that you can connect it to a variable. To do this you change code connections.

I usually use this as the final option in code connections:

Doc root var: `_whatever`

Then in MainScene.m (automatically created by Spritebuilder in Xcode) you write this code and add on:

```
CCTextField * _whatever
//your code
```

Publish and run and the Textfield should be clickable.